# Calling mmap in C++, compile using Clang

Tags: c++, clang, mmap, clang++

I'm trying to allocate memory using mmap in C++ and compile using Clang/Clang++, but when I compile my code I get an error. The code:

```
// test.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main() {
    int *a = static_cast<int*>(mmap(0x20000, sizeof(int), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0));
    *a = 13;
    return 0;
}
```

The error:

```
test.cpp:6:29: error: no matching function for call to 'mmap'
    int *a = static_cast<int*>(mmap(0x20000, sizeof(int), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0));
                               ^~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/mman.h:57:14: note: candidate function   not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'void *' for 1st argument
extern void *mmap (void *__addr, size_t __len, int __prot,
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Compiling with Clang or Clang++ gives the same error. Does anyone know the correct way to call mmap in C++? The exact same program works perfectly fine if it's a *.c file.

EDIT: Also I mean in the *.c version of this I remove the static cast and it'll work.

Comment: the error says it all. "no known conversion from 'int' to 'void *' for 1st argument" the first arg must be a pointer, not a number

Comment: "The exact same program works perfectly fine if it's a \*.c file." - It may *compile* as C. That doesn't mean it *works* - even if it runs.

Comment: @pm100 Thanks you're right, once I reinterpret cast the number int a void pointer it works.

Comment: How do you know 0x20000 is a good address to map? Where is it coming from?

Comment: @SergeyA I actually don't know, but I'm right now just trying to play around with mmap to see if I can allocate memory at specific addresses. mmap actually doesn't always allocate specifically at the provided address, the pointer to address is actually a "hint" for where the OS should allocate the memory: https://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap

Comment: @putiiii I am well aware of this. I was wondering if you are. Usually providing constants like that to mmap() is useless. Obviously, if you are just playing with it, it's OK.